# Highcharts export (PhantomJS) to server does not show words

Tags: php, highcharts, phantomjs

I have tried to export a picture of a pie chart into my server, but I can't see labels or titles. I have tested the options.json file in a server at http://export.highcharts.com/demo and it worked just fine. This is my options contant:

```
{
series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    data: [
            ['one',   80.0],
            ['two', 10],
            ['three',   10],
          ]
    }],
    title: {
           text: 'The Title',
           style: { color: '#333' }
   }
}
```

And this is how the output looks:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but it looks like you have to install specific fonts on your server. The export- server cannot find them. For Linux, place your fonts in /usr/share/fonts and run from the commandline:

`$prompt> fc-cache -fv`

to refresh the font cache on the system.

Comment: Great answer! i have installed the basic Microsoft fonts pack and the problem solved :)